# Application crash at stl string creation

Tags: c++, stl, windbg

I am getting an application crash in two locations of my application. One of the locations is the following statement of the method given below. The application crashes while creating an stl string object for the string pass to LogMessage method.

```
EMCoreLogger::GetLoggerInstance()->LogMessage("Sending message completed successfully",
                            "CGEMCustomMessageService",Information);
```

The callstack is given below

```
    msvcr90.dll!_crt_debugger_hook(int _Reserved=101180712)  Line 65    C
    msvcr90.dll!_invalid_parameter(const wchar_t * pszExpression=0x00000000, const wchar_t * pszFunction=0x00000000, const wchar_t * pszFile=0x00000000, unsigned int nLine=0, unsigned int pReserved=0)  Line 112 + 0x7 bytes  C++
    msvcr90.dll!memcpy_s(void * dst=0x0607e5d8, unsigned int sizeInBytes=0, const void * src=0x084beac8, unsigned int count=38)  Line 55 + 0x19 bytes   C
    msvcp90.dll!std::char_traits<char>::_Copy_s(char * _First1=0x0607e5d8, unsigned int _Size_in_bytes=0, const char * _First2=0x084beac8, unsigned int _Count=38)  Line 583    C++
    msvcp90.dll!std::_Traits_helper::copy_s<std::char_traits<char> >(char * _First1=0x0607e5d8, unsigned int _Size=0, const char * _First2=0x084beac8, unsigned int _Count=38, std::_Secure_char_traits_tag __formal={...})  Line 714 + 0x11 bytes  C++
    msvcp90.dll!std::_Traits_helper::copy_s<std::char_traits<char> >(char * _First1=0x0607e5d8, unsigned int _Size=0, const char * _First2=0x084beac8, unsigned int _Count=38)  Line 706 + 0x14 bytes   C++
    msvcp90.dll!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign(const char * _Ptr=0x084beac8, unsigned int _Count=38)  Line 1086 + 0x1b bytes  C++
    msvcp90.dll!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign(const char * _Ptr=0x084beac8)  Line 1095 + 0x16 bytes  C++
    msvcp90.dll!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >(const char * _Ptr=0x084beac8)  Line 664   C++
>   GemCore.dll!CGEMCustomMessageService::SendProcessMessage(unsigned short tkt=167, SSECSMSG * mb=0x0607eafc, int nFuncID=4, int * pnClientIds=0x1bf5aff8, int nClientCount=1)  Line 566 + 0x34 bytes  C++
    GemCore.dll!CCustomMessageRouter::PA_ProcessPrimaryMessage(unsigned short tkt=167, SSECSMSG * mb=0x0607eafc, int nFuncID=4, int * pnClientIds=0x1bf5aff8, int nClientCount=1)  Line 54 + 0x1d bytes C++
    PAL.dll!CPALProtocolPlugin::PA_ProcessPrimaryMessage(unsigned short tkt=167, SSECSMSG * mb=0x0607eafc, int nFuncID=4, int * pnClientIds=0x1bf5aff8, int nClientCount=1)  Line 50 + 0x2c bytes   C++
    CustomSECSII_R.dll!CCustomMessageTransportPlugin::ProcessPrmryMsg(char * pBuffer=0x4794cfe0, unsigned long dwBufSize=31, bool bRepExpected=true, unsigned char byStream='', unsigned char byFunction='', unsigned short tkt=167, int nFuncID=4, int * pnClientIds=0x1bf5aff8, int nClientCount=1)  Line 85 + 0x20 bytes C++
    TAL.dll!CMessageHandler::HandleCustomMessage(char * pBuffer=0x4794cfe0, unsigned long dwBufSize=31, bool bRepExpected=true, unsigned long dwTransID=2839, unsigned long dwTransTwoID=0, unsigned char byStream='', unsigned char byFunction='', unsigned char * pHeader=0x478f8ff0, unsigned char byPType=0, int nScanFuncId=-1, int nProcessFuncId=4, std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> > pVecClientId=[1](1))  Line 2949 + 0x4b bytes   C++
    TAL.dll!CMessageHandler::ReceiveMessage(char * pBuffer=0x4794cfe0, unsigned long dwBufSize=31, bool bRepExpected=true, unsigned long dwTransID=2839, unsigned long dwTransTwoID=0, unsigned char byStream='', unsigned char byFunction='', unsigned char * pHeader=0x478f8ff0, unsigned char byPType=0)  Line 1220 + 0x6c bytes C++
    TAL.dll!CTALTransportObject::ReceiveMessage(char * szBuffer=0x4794cfe0, unsigned long dwBufSize=31, bool bRepExpected=true, unsigned long dwSECS1TRID=2839, unsigned long dwSECS2TRID=0, unsigned char byStream='', unsigned char byFunction='', unsigned char * pbyHeader=0x478f8ff0, unsigned char byPType=0)  Line 199 + 0x30 bytes  C++
    HSMS.dll!CDataMessageMngr::RespondToMessage(CMessage * pMessage=0x0607ff28)  Line 392   C++
    HSMS.dll!CLowerRouter::RecieveData()  Line 820  C++
    HSMS.dll!CLowerRouter::RecievingThread(void * pVoid=0x036f9fa0)  Line 566   C++
    kernel32.dll!7c80b729()     
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]
```

I enabled **pageheap** to detect heap corruption. I also enabled **Run-Time Error Checks /RTCs** to detect stack corruption. I am not able to detect the root cause.

***How can I proceed to get the cause of the issue?***

```
bool
CGEMCustomMessageService::SendProcessMessage(SECSTICKET tkt, PSECSMSG mb,int nFuncID, int* pnClientIds,int nClientCount)
{
    bool bRetCode = true;
    int nRetCode = 0;
    char chLog[1024] = {0};
    CEALCustomMessagePlugin *pCustomMessagePlugin = CEALCustomMessagePlugin::Instance();
    int nStream   = mb->nStream;
    int nFunction = mb->nFunction;
    int nTicket   = tkt;

        CGEMEqpmntService* pGEMEqpmntService = (CGEMEqpmntService *)CGEMEqpmntService::Instance();
        EQP_CTRL_STATE eControlState = STATE_HOSTOFFLINE;
        sprintf(chLog,"Sending S%d,F%d with ticket[%d]",mb->nStream, mb->nFunction,tkt);
        LogDataMessage(chLog,"CGEMCustomMessageService",Information);

        if (NULL != pCustomMessagePlugin)
        {  

                    GEMCoreLogger::GetLoggerInstance()->LogMessage("Control state is Online remote sending message to client",
                        "CGEMCustomMessageService",Debug);
                    nRetCode = pCustomMessagePlugin->GEMT_ProcessPrimaryMessage(tkt,mb,nFuncID,pnClientIds,nClientCount);

                    GEMCoreLogger::GetLoggerInstance()->LogMessage("Sending message completed successfully",
                        "CGEMCustomMessageService",Information);
        }

    return bRetCode;
}
```

Comment: @unapersson: It is an enumeration value.

Comment: Woulf be better if yu pasted the stack dump as text.

Comment: What is the signature of `LogMessage`?

Comment: Did you do a full rebuild (clean/rebuild) after enabling the above features?

Comment: The signature of the LogMessage is void LogMessage(const string &crstrLogMessage, const string &crstrSource, LogMessageType logMessageType);

Comment: @Maanu I'd guess that something has corrupted your heap long before LogMessage gets called.

Comment: @MArtin: I rebuild all the modules after enabling the feature. The same thread always crashes

Answer (score 5):

I think you should start by giving up all your beliefs.

Next, take a look into the call stack: the function call you blame isn't even there.  All seems go well up till the `memcpy_s`.  Then work your way back by asking questions like: where dit `memcpy_s` get it's parameters from?  Who filled them in?  Why were they filled in that way?...

In troubleshooting, you become a detective.  Suspect everybody (but start with your own code :) ).  Be wary of prejudice, and of  words like 'should', 'think that...', 'will never, ever, ever, ... ' etc...  Go for hard facts only.

Try to diminish the number of suspects by reasoning, based on your knowledge of the system and on facts you gather by debugging.

(by the way, the call stack can become more helpful after loading the symbols for some of the kernel dlls, following the tips on [this Visual Studio article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/04/27/412764.aspx))

And if all that doesn't help, ask someone on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Wary. And +1 for that cosmic first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this form in the call:

```
    EMCoreLogger::GetLoggerInstance()->LogMessage( string("Sending message completed successfully"), string("CGEMCustomMessageService"), Information);
```